# Change the author of an issue in GitHub

Tags: github

We are migrating the issues of a project from Google Code to GitHub. Google's migration tool assigns all the issues in GitHub to the user `GoogleCodeExporter`. How can I change issue's author in GitHub?

Comment: Now all the old users are on Github, right? Otherwise how would you map them?

Comment: Right. The Google code users are on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GitHub API has a function to [edit issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue) that will allow you to change the *assignee* (not *creator*) of the issue. As far as I know, there is no functionality within GitHub to change the *creator*.

I'm sorry that this doesn't accomplish exactly what you want to do, but it might be the closest alternative (depending on what your project uses issue creator for).

Comment: Yeah, changing assignee is definitely not the same. For one case where it matters, I like to look at Author:me on other people's issue trackers to check in on issues I've filed. To find all pre- and post- migration issues, I'd need to look for Author:me _and_ Assignee:me, not to mention the fact that I don't want to be "assigned" on issues just to be able to find them again.